# Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

Tags: android

**There are 3 causes of errors that I get in my logcat**

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

below is my logcat.

```
 Process: pnj.uas.aufar, PID: 4529
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pnj.uas.aufar/pnj.uas.aufar.TambahCatatanActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2914)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at pnj.uas.aufar.TambahCatatanActivity.onCreate(TambahCatatanActivity.java:27)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7140)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7131)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2894)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:241)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:215)
2022-01-22 07:32:04.703 4529-4529/pnj.uas.aufar E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:143)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:113)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:474)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:433)
            ... 28 more
```

**Below file for TambahCatatanActivity.java**

```
package pnj.uas.aufar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class TambahCatatanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edJudul, edJumlah, edTanggal;
    Button btnSimpan;

    RealmHelper realm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tambah_catatan);

        realm = new  RealmHelper(TambahCatatanActivity.this);

        edJudul = findViewById(R.id.ed_judul);
        edJumlah = findViewById(R.id.ed_jumlah);
        edTanggal = findViewById(R.id.ed_tanggal);
        btnSimpan = findViewById(R.id.btn_simpan);

        edTanggal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //date picker
                final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                int nowYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int nowMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int nowDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(TambahCatatanActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        cal.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
                        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
                        edTanggal.setText(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
                    }
                }, nowYear, nowMonth, nowDay);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        btnSimpan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CatatanModel catatan = new CatatanModel();
                catatan.setId((int) realm.getNextId());
                catatan.setJudul(edJudul.getText().toString());
                catatan.setJumlahhutang(edJumlah.getText().toString());
                catatan.setTanggal(edTanggal.getText().toString());

                realm.insertData(catatan);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**And the last one is the file for activity_tambah_catatan.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".TambahCatatanActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/ed_judul"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hutang Anda" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/ed_jumlah"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Jumlah Hutang"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/ed_tanggal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:hint="Tanggal Jatuh Tempo" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_simpan"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Simpan"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

build.gradle add `implementation com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0`